# you are about to over ride how thunderbird identifies this site

Tags: email, thunderbird, imap

I am using Thunderbird for emails but I am getting error as in the screenshot.
[image: thunderbird problem]
What is the problem why is thunderbird complaining.
It is running in Vmware Workstation VM.

**update 1**
I was trying to capture the screenshot of the signature as mentioned in the comments. Even after rebooting in later, I did not had the situation to capture the same error. However, as soon as possible it generated the error for which I had opened the question here is the screenshot.
[ssl certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmY4V.jpg)

Comment: Either your date and time is wrong on your computer or something is most likely intercepting your secure communication with imap.gmail.com. Could be an anti-virus with an email scanner or some type of network security appliance. More nefariously it could be malware. Use the ‘view’ option and post the details of the certificate that is presented.

Comment: In order to answer this question we must know more about the certificate.  Please edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Please click [View...] and include a screenshot of the window shown there.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the screenshot below update 1 (ssl certificate) as you mentioned. AVG is running on host machine not in Virtual machine.

Comment: @hindanomera - This issue isn’t caused by AVG.  You should immediately remove it and replace it with security software that doesn’t install insecure certificates signed by AVG.  The guest OS is indicating that the certificate it was expecting was going to be signed by Google but the one it received was signed by AVG.  The removal of AVG from the host OS will solve your broke security.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the problem why is thunderbird complaining?

The rootcause of this popup warning is that the certificate that you are using is issued by a certification authority (CA) that you have not (yet) marked as *trusted*.

So use the *view* option to find the real reason for that, like who is the CA that issued the certificate, and then act accordingly. I.e decide if you trust it or not.